# Which form of past time?

Tags: past-tense

I have a question. From [Wikipedia's article about Oprah's book club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oprah%27s_Book_Club):

> "The club **has seen** several literary controversies, such as Jonathan Franzen's public dissatisfaction with his novel The Corrections **having been chosen** by Winfrey"

The club is closed for all time.  Why *"has seen"* and not just "*saw*"? Why *"having been chosen"* and not just "*been chosen"* or *"chose by"*?

Comment: Try this link. It explains the usage of ***[Perfect Tenses](http://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-perfect-tense-definition-examples.html)***

Comment: "has seen" instead of just "saw" signifies that the it was an ongoing  process and took some time, "having been chosen" is also continuity of the tense.

Answer (score 3):

1. > Why *has seen* and not just *saw*?

   Wikipedia articles are continually revised and updated by many hands working independently. I think it very likely that this passage was written before the Club closed.
2. > Why *having been chosen* and not just *been chosen* or *chose by*?

   The underlying 'canonical' form is a past perfect passive:

   > Franzen was dissatisfied that his book ***had been chosen***

   The nominalization of *dissatisfied* to *dissatisfaction* requires a complement of the form *with X*, with X cast in a form which behaves like a noun phrase—in this case, the gerund *having been chosen*.

   Neither of your rewrites represents this sense or is even grammatically valid.

Comment: You'd never know what was intended from the *spoken* form, but in the written form the source of Franzen's dissatisfaction could be cast in the possessive - *dissatisfaction with his novel The **Corrections'** having been chosen.*